# How to create a Reusable React Native Components that can be used across Multiple Projects

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created few components in React Native and i want to use the same set of component in another React native project without copy pasting those list of components.js files into my new project.

Is there a way to combine all the reusable components into a library that i can refer in my new project and call the Components in that library.

Comment: Like any other JS module.

Comment: I want it in React Native across multiple projects

Comment: Like any other JS module.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that. You have to create your own npm module. You can do it locally. [Here is guide how to do that](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules)

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same without using NPM repository..?

Comment: I am sure there is but I don't see any point of doing it where the npm is already straight forward enough.

Comment: Yeah, We are in need to use the components for the multiple projects for our internal use.
Could you please recommend the way to do it without NPM.